# PHP IMAP email content and MySQL encoding

Tags: php, mysql, email, encoding, imap

This is a problem I've been battling for a long time. I really hope someone can help me.

I have a PHP program reading emails from an IMAP mailbox. After fidgeting with the PHP IMAP functions for a while, I managed to get the plain text content of the email inside a variable.

When I do a var_dump of this variable in a log file, I get something good and readable.

However, when I try to save the value of this variable to my MySQL database, it *sometimes* fails depending on the encoding of the original email.

I say it's due to encoding only because it often fails at the first "special character". Hence, only part of the email is displayed.

Is there any way I can "sanitize" the value of that variable to be used in my MySQL database? The collation of my MySQL database is currently set to *utf8_unicode_ci*.

This is the decoding function I've been using up until now:

```
static function decode_text($text, $encoding)
{
    //return quoted_printable_decode($text);
    switch ( $encoding ) {
        # 7BIT
        case 0:
            return imap_utf7_decode($text);
        # 8BIT
        case 1:
            return imap_utf8($text);
        # BINARY
        case 2:
            return imap_binary($text);
        # BASE64
        case 3:
            return imap_base64($text);
        # QUOTED-PRINTABLE
        case 4:
            return imap_qprint($text);
        # OTHER
        case 5:
            return $text;
        # UNKNOWN
        default:
            return $text;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are storing imap emails in a mysql database, you need not.

Comment: Properly done, PHP+MySQL never needs decodes like in your function.  So I will assume Imap is the problem.  Please provide the encoding and the desired decoding -- both in hex -- of a sample.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this [github repository](https://github.com/optimumweb/php-email-reader-parser) to deal with this issue.

> reading emails from a mailbox using IMAP and then parsing the returned emails into a dev-friendly object.